# Uri issue with Sending mail with multiple attachments with Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE android

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I am trying to send a mail via default mail client in android.This mail may have multiple attachments (Maximum 4 images and a audio).

Here user can either take photo with camera or select an existing image.So , I am using Intent with action "Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE" and pass an Arraylist of Uris as an ParcelableArrayListExtra to the intent to attach the files.

In other threads here , I found that suggestions are given to use file://something  Uri but if I do this no file is attached. But If I use content://something Uri then files are attached fine.But I have an serious problem. When I select images from the galary then images are attached correctly but If I take photo with camera then a content://somehitng uri is returned and added to the ParcelableArrayList correctly but no image is being attached that are just taken , but galary images are attaching just fine.

Here is my codes...

```
package com.ayon.camera;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button add1, add2, mail;
    ImageView image1, image2;
    Uri uri1 , uri2 ;
    ArrayList<Uri> list ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        add1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add1);
        add2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add2);
        mail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mail);
        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

        list = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        add1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String fileName = "temp.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                        fileName);
                uri1 = getContentResolver()
                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        uri1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });

        add2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String fileName = "temp.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                        fileName);
                uri2 = getContentResolver()
                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        uri2);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        });

        mail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String []{"ashiq.ayon@gmail.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");
                //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri1);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, list);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending Mail"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            System.out.println("Uri 1 = " + uri1);
            list.add(uri1);
            image1.setImageURI(uri1);
        }

        if(requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            System.out.println("Uri 2 = " + uri2);
            list.add(uri2);
            image2.setImageURI(uri2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually , what I found is , when I capture image with camera the image is not added to galary immediately.So , somehow the uri returned from camera didn't work for attaching that image. I changed the code to add the captured image to galary immediately.Then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

When sending the intent:

```
File scrapFile = new File(path, "path/to/file");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(scrapFile));
```

In onActivityResult:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```